# How to search array items in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic3, observable

Please I'm using a model name ResProject and variable resProject : Observable ;

this is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";    

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-project',
  templateUrl: 'project.html',
})
export class ProjectPage {
  resProject : Observable <ResProject[]> ;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams)
```

and for the models of ResProject its like that :

```
export interface ResProject {
    key?: string;
    type : string ;
    name : string; 
    nbrUnit : number ; 
    nbrFloor : number ;
}
```

and for the HTML this is my code :

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let rp of resProject  | async" detail-push navPush="ViewProjectPage" [navParams]="{resProject:rp} "  >
    {{rp.name}}
  </ion-item>
```

Please note that i get the data of Resproject from  firebase.

How can i filter this list of ResProject in my `ion-serchbar` or any other solutions?

Comment: Can you share full code that you have. Observables can be filtered using pipe and filter operator

Comment: thanks  this is my full ts file and html file 
https://github.com/thameurr/ionicconnectdb/issues/1

Comment: Awesome, i ll chime in how i would do it

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: Please Check this link it will helps you https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Comment: debounceTime not found :(

Comment: why don't you use custom pipe to filter array.
Something like this => *ngFor="let rp of resProject  | async | customPipe: filterString"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you seem to be using Observables (Rxjs), and these are not Arrays hence you can not use .filter etc array methods directly with Observables. You can either implement filter using Observable's operator "filter": https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Or you can just subscribe to your service (that returns Observable) in the constructor and then make your template work using arrays (and hence yo won't need async pipe in the template).

Try to do the following in your TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ResProject,ComProject,OffiProject } from "../../models/project.model";
import { AddProjectService } from "../../services/addproject.service";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-project',
  templateUrl: 'project.html',
})
export class ProjectPage {

  // holders of original unfiltered data:
  resProject : Observable <ResProject[]> ;
  comProject : Observable <ComProject[]>;

  // holders of data for filtered lists, initially set to empty array:
  filteredResProject: any[] = [];
  filteredComProject: any[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public projectService : AddProjectService,
              ) 
    { 
      this.initializeItems();
    }

  filterItems(event) {
    this.initializeItems();
    const val = event.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.filteredResProject = this.filteredResProject.filter((item) => {
        return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.resProject = this.projectService.getResProjectList()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key : c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      }

    )
  this.resProject.subscribe( res => {
    this.filteredResProject = res;
  })

  this.comProject = this.projectService.getComProjectList()
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map(
    changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({
        key : c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
      }))
    }

  )
this.comProject.subscribe( res => {
  this.filteredComProject = res;
});
  }

}
```

And in your template yoo should not be using async pipe anymore as you only render arrays based data:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    <ion-title>Project List</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content >
    <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>
        Project List
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-badge>Number Of Residential Project :{{ resProject.length }}</ion-badge>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let rp of filteredResProject" detail-push navPush="ViewProjectPage" [navParams]="{resProject:rp} ">
        {{rp.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-badge color="danger">Number Of Commercial Project :{{ comProject.length }}</ion-badge>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let cp of filteredComProject" detail-push navPush="ViewComProPage" [navParams]="{comProject:cp}">
        {{cp.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

This is not the best code design tbh but based on your current code this should work. Basic idea - you want to obtain full truth data from your service and on each "initialize" you only modify filtered lists.

Comment: Thank you very much its working thank you so much for your help, i just add `(ionClear)="initializeItems()"` in the html

Comment: great;) and nice one catch re ionClear!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method to filter array items as below.

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of resProject">
    {{ item.name }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**HomePage.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  resProject: any[];

  constructor() {

   this.initializeItems();
  }

  filterItems(event) {

    this.initializeItems();
    const val = event.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.resProject = this.resProject.filter((item: ResProject) => {
        return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.resProject = [
      { name: "Andrew" },
      { name: "Micheal" }, 
      { name: "Bernad" },
      { name: "Charles" }, 
      { name: "David" }];
  }
}

export interface ResProject {
    name : string; 
}
```

Hope this will help you. find working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wbkadp?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: thanks for your reply i get this error : Typescript Error
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ResProject[]'.
src/pages/project/project.ts
this.resProject = this.resProject.filter((item) => {
  return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
})

Comment: Not working also i need all the value for each project like the models `export interface ResProject {
    key?: string;
    type : string ;
    name : string; 
    nbrUnit : number ; 
    nbrFloor : number ;
}`

Comment: I just show an example how you need to achieve it.  re-arranging code as your requirement is up to you.

Comment: yes i understand and thanks for your help and your time but if i use it like you told me i can't get my data from firebase and i get this error : `Type 'Observable<{ key: string; type: string; name: string; nbrUnit: number; nbrFloor: number; }[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 22 more.`

Comment: I gave the correct answer to your question. if it correct mark it as the correct answer and if this is a new error post it as a separate question in stackoverflow.

Comment: @ Sudarshana Dayananda thanks for your help and i mark it correct because your solution its working but not on my code